# how to create a file on fly in java structs

Tags: java, struct

i need to create a csv file based on array list values and how to upload it to ftp server i need file to get created on fly and pass it ftp method so it gets uploaded to ftp server

```
public ActionForward generatePayroll(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
                       HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
   SessionInfoForm _form = (SessionInfoForm) form;
   SisTransactionsSession _config = _form.getSisTransactionsSession();
   String loggedInUser = _form.getLoggedinEmployeeDVO().getLoginId().toUpperCase();
   String[] business = request.getParameterValues("selectedBusinessValues");
   String[] position = request.getParameterValues("selectedPositionValues");
   File file= new File("PAYROLL_PRM.csv");
   InputStream isFixedValue = null;
   try {
      // create FileWriter object with file as parameter
      FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
      // add data to csv
      fileWriter.write(business.toString());
      fileWriter.write(position.toString());

      // closing writer connection
      //fileWriter.flush();
      isFixedValue = new BufferedInputStream(fileWriter.getInputStream());
      fileWriter.close();
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return mapping.findForward("success");
}
```

the below method works to upload file to ftp server

```
private boolean fileUpload(InputStream isUploadFile, String dirName, String loggedInUser,  String fileName){
     boolean storeRetVal = false;
  String fileType = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fileName.length());
     storeRetVal = SISSFTPManager.getInstance().put(isUploadFile, dirName, fileName);
     if (storeRetVal)
     {
         try {
        if (fileType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("csv")){
           ICSAPI.getInstance().getSIMSOrderManager().createFileAudit(loggedInUser, fileName);
        } else {

        }
   } catch (RemoteException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (SystemException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (ApplicationException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
     logger.info("BulkUploadAction:fileUpload SFTP Transfer file successfully!");
     } else {
         logger.error("BulkUploadAction:fileUpload SFTP Transfer file FAILED!");          
     }       
    
  return storeRetVal;
 }
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can get `InputStream` using `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `ByteArrayInputStream`. You don't need to create the file.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(bos)) {
    writer.write(business.toString());
    writer.write(position.toString());
}
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
```